# What approaches are there to re-designing 8/16-bit sprites for HD?

Tags: sprites

I'm new to game development, and my skills with Photoshop are not that great.

I was planning to try to convert a old game to HD, but for this I need HD sprites. What is a good way to approach converting 8/16 bit sprites into something like HD? I mean something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can't "just" convert a low-resolution image to a high resolution one.  In sonic's case, he was redrawn completely.  There are a few scaling algorithms that do a "best guess" interpolation for pixel sprites such as [2×SaI and hqnx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling)

Comment: You can also check some programs that make vectorization for you, e.g. Inkscape's "trace bitmap".

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I've tried Inkscape and it doesn't do that good of a job. I will probably need to redrawn the image like Draco18s said. I was thinking drawing them on paper and then vectorize with illustrator...

Comment: You might find some aspects of [Doing an HD Remake the Right Way](http://www.fortressofdoors.com/doing-an-hd-remake-the-right-way/) interesting.

Answer (score -5):

you could try waifu 2X thing is youll have to make all the sprites look antialised first. find a way to size them up using the other methods people already mentioned, then re scale them down using Berlinier sampling, and then upload it to http://waifu2x.udp.jp/    and youll be happy[image]

legit what i got it to do, to the donkey Kong game over screen.

Comment: There's a pretty large difference between this and small pixel art.